# Confusing Integral Expression: $\int{\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this integral expression to be evaluated:

> $$\int{\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx}$$

I've followed these steps:

1. Completed the square in $x$ and then substituted $u=x-\frac{1}{2}.$
2. Trig substituted $u = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan t.$ and then simplified the equation thereby giving:

$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{3}\sec^2t}{\sqrt{3}\tan t+\sqrt{3}\sec t+1}dt}$$

I know up to this, but I'm unclear what to do next.
Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I know it’s not a substitute for an explanation, but this [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), which shows steps with explanation, might help you $\ddot\smile$ (+1, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start considering the integrand as $$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}=\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\times\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x-\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}=\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x-1}=\frac x {x-1}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x-1}$$